# Reactjs add onChange to props.children dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React v16 (latest) and I'm trying to create a general form component, that uses props.children.

```
export class MyForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form">
                <h3>{this.props.formName}</h3>
                <div>
                  {React.Children.map(this.props.children, t => {return <span>{t}<br></br></span>;})}
                </div>
                <input type="button" value={this.props.formName} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
            </div>
        </div>
       )
    }
}
```

I want to create small form that just are able to create a meaningful json object and send it in POST

This is an example of such usage:

```
<MyForm>
   <input type="text" name="a1"></input>
   <input type="text" name="a2"></input>
</MyForm>
```

And I want to have many such small forms. Problem is I want each child (props.children) to have an onChange event -

```
onChange(event) // name is "a1" or "a2", like in the example aboce
{
 var obj = {};
 obj[name]=event.target.value;
 this.setState(obj);
}
```

-so that I don't need to manually add onChange for each such child
-I guess another solution is to create a  component, but I want the form to be flexible for each kind of sub-element (input text, text area, radio buttons,...) and I just want them all to have similar onChange that will set the name of the component and its value to the state...

I tried adding an onChange property in consturctor and in different hooks, but got:

cannot define property 'onChange', object is not extensible

So when are where (if at all) can I add an onChange dynamically to props.children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great use case for a Higher Order Component. You can use a HOC to wrap and add the `onChange` prop to any component:

```
const WithOnChange = WrappedComponent => {
    return class extends Component {
        onChange = e => {
            const obj = {};
            obj[name]=e.target.value;
            this.setState(obj);
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} onChange={this.onChange} />
        }
    }
}

...

import Input from './Input';

class MyForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                ...
                <Input type="text" name="a1" />
                ...
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default MyForm;

....

import WithOnChange from './WithOnChange';

const Input = (props) => (
    <input {...props} />
);

export default WithOnChange(Input);
```

**EDIT:**

Another option is to move your children map into a higher order component and then create a custom `<Form />` component:

```
const Form = () => {
    return <form>{this.props.children}</form>
};

export default WithOnChange(Form);

const WithOnChange = WrappedComponent => {
    return class extends Component {
        onChange = e => {
            const obj = {};
            obj[name] = e.target.value;
            this.setState(obj);
        }

        render () {
            const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
                return React.cloneElement(child, { onChange: this.onChange });
            });
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>{children}</WrappedComponent>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this leaves me at exactly the same place - in MyForm there is no <input>... just anonymous props.children... Could you explain some more?

Comment: Yep, instead you can wrap an input as a separate component. Then you would use something like `<Input />`.

Comment: @user967710 Updated answer

Comment: @user967710 Made another update showing a slightly different approach. Either should work.

Comment: So the answer is much simpler, I just needed React.cloneElement, to impose my onChange on myChildren. thx

Comment: Right, but if you are using this same pattern for multiple forms in your app, I would create the HOC or custom `Form` component so you aren't repeating code throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

@user967710, can you please test the following code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    debugger;
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = event.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
  }
<MyForm formName="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="a1" onChange={this.onChange}></input>
  <input type="text" name="a2" onChange={this.onChange}></input>
</MyForm>
```

Comment: This is ok, but i wanted to avoid passing the onchange + name should be "a1" or "a2", so that needs to be passed in as well to _onChange.

Wanted to avoid this boilerplate